# Validate Json Not Empty when Using JsonResource in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm attempting to download content from Shopify with OhMyBrew - BasicShopifyApi and save to database. Before doing so I have created a JsonResource to sort the data provided by orders.json from Shopify.

How do I validate that the array is set(isset) or is not empty?

Does Laravel have a validator or helper that can assist with this task?

I have created a validateJsonNotEmpty and it is called for each resource function eg.

ValidateJsonNotEmpty Helper Function:

```
public function validateJsonNotEmpty($array1, $array2 = null, $array3 = null) {
        if($array1 && $array2 && $array3) {
            if (isset($this->resource[$array1][$array2][$array3])) {
                return $this->resource[$array1][$array2][$array3];
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        elseif($array1 && $array2) {
            if (isset($this->resource[$array1][$array2])) {
                return $this->resource[$array1][$array2];
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } elseif ($array1) {
            if (isset($this->resource[$array1])) {
                return $this->resource[$array1];
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

shopifyResource file (jsonresource:

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $orderCustomerArray = array(
            'email' => $this->validateJsonNotEmpty('email'),
...
)
```

This works, however, is there a more efficient way to validateJsonNotEmpty in Laravel?